# jqGrid and datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid, datepicker

I've searched but I don't understand how to make this work...

I want to use a date picker on Add Form...

How can I do this .....

Thank you

```html
$(function () {
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: "bftri.php",
        datatype: "xml",
        mtype: "GET",
        colNames: ["id","Date", "Libelle", "Participant","Lieu","Format","Site","Type","Composition"],
        colModel: [
   { name: "id", width: 30},
            {name:'date', index:'date', label: 'Date', width: 80,editable: true }
        ],
```

And i have beforeshowform.....

```
beforeShowForm: function(form) { 
    $('#tr_date', form).hide();
    $('#tr_libelle', form).hide();
    $('#tr_lieu', form).hide();
    $('#tr_format', form).hide();
    $('#tr_site', form).hide();
    $('#tr_type', form).hide();
    $('#tr_composition', form).hide();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `editoptions.dataInit` for example. The code will look like

```js
{
    name: "date",
    label: "Date",
    width: 80,
    editable: true,
    editoptions: {
        dataInit: function (elem) {
            $(elem).datepicker({
                //dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", // !!! you need set correct dateFormat
                //autoSize: true,
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                showWeek: true
            });
        }

    }
}
```

It's important that you use correct `dateFormat` option of the jQuery UI Datepicker which correspond format of your data.

The code of `beforeShowForm` looks very strange. Why you hide all input field of the edit form? If you hide the row which allows editing of `date` column (see `$('#tr_date', form).hide()`) then you will not be able to edit it and will not be able to use Datepicker too.

Comment: Thanks, yes i made a mistake on the beforeshowform... But the code doesn't work for me. Is there import to do ?

Comment: @You are welcome! What "import" you mean? It's difficult to help you if the problem description is just "the code doesn't work for me". Do you see Input field for the date in the editing mode? Do you see Datepicker if you click in the filed? Probably [the small demo with datepicker](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simpleNavGrid1.htm) will halp you to find your error.

Comment: Thanks to you i found that <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> was missing in my code....